# Downloading a file from google cloud storage inside a folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I've got a python script that gets a list of files that have been uploaded to a google cloud storage bucket, and attempts to retrieve the data as a string.

The code is simply:

```
file = open(base_dir + "/" + path, 'wb')
data =  Blob(path, bucket).download_as_string()
file.write(data)
```

My issue is that the data I've uploaded is stored inside folders in the bucket, so the path would be something like:

```
folder/innerfolder/file.jpg
```

When the google library attempts to download the file, it gets it in the form of a GET request, which turns the above path into:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket/o/folder%2Finnerfolder%2Ffile.jpg
```

Is there any way to stop this happening / download the file though this way? Cheers.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes - you can do this with the python [storage client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python).

Just install it with `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage` and then use the following code:

```
from google.cloud import storage

# Initialise a client
storage_client = storage.Client("[Your project name here]")
# Create a bucket object for our bucket
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
# Create a blob object from the filepath
blob = bucket.blob("folder_one/foldertwo/filename.extension")
# Download the file to a destination
blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
```

You can also use `.download_as_string()` but as you're writing it to a file anyway downloading straight to the file may be easier.

The only slightly awkward thing to be aware of is that the filepath is the path from *after* the bucket name, so doesn't line up exactly with the path on the web interface.

Comment: How can this be done in C#?  I am having trouble getting an object inside a folder within a bucket.   eg:  bucket/folder/objectINeed.jpeg

Comment: Hi, @dspyank I am using C# and experiencing the same problem,  I can download files from the bucket but not from inside a directory , I get the error message :"Exception thrown: 'Google.GoogleApiException' in mscorlib.dll"

Comment: `get_bucket()` should jus be `bucket()` otherwise you may get an authentication error.

Comment: I have used the same logic and the file gets downloaded but it cannot be opened. The actual file size doesn't match the downloaded file size.

Comment: Adding to @RichardWhitehead's comment, the `get_bucket()` method requires that "the authenticated user [has] the storage.buckets.get IAM permission." ([api reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/get)). `storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)` simply instantiates and returns the bucket object ([ref](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/73d033d9df92f6a161f1567bbd8ff6270a38b72a/google/cloud/storage/client.py#L293-L310)). This is a better solution for the OP.