# Reading a pandas pickle file in Tensorflow in CloudML

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm getting an error trying to read a pandas pickle e.g. `df.to_pickle()` method, which is stored in Google Cloud storage. I'm trying to do the following:

```
path_to_gcs_file = 'gs://xxxxx'
f = file_io.FileIO(path_to_gcs_file, mode='r').read()
train_df = pd.read_pickle(f)
f.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Alternatively I tried:

```
f = BytesIO(file_io.read_file_to_string(path_to_gcs_file, binary_mode=True))
train_df = pd.read_pickle(f)
```

Which works locally but not on CloudML!

```
f = file_io.read_file_to_string(path_to_gcs_file, binary_mode=True)
train_df = pd.read_pickle(f)
```

Gives me an error:
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get away with using a context manager, but I think you're pulling the end of the certificate using this way, so you should instead download the file through the api

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```

Then

```
# Initialise a client
storage_client = storage.Client("[Your project name here]")
# Create a bucket object for our bucket
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
# Create a blob object from the filepath
blob = bucket.blob("folder_one/foldertwo/filename.extension")
# Download the file to a destination
blob.download_to_filename(path_to_gcs_file)
with open(path_to_gcs_file, "rb" as f:
    train_df = = pickle.load(f)
```

Much was taken from this answer:
[Downloading a file from google cloud storage inside a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555142/downloading-a-file-from-google-cloud-storage-inside-a-folder)

Comment: I'm getting UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 6488: ordinal not in range(128). I'm guessing it could be python version issue?

Comment: I'm also using `df.to_pickle()` to create the pickle

Comment: Have you tried the above method instead? pickle.load() will return a df object if the original dumped object was a df

Comment: Yes, your exact code gives me the error I commented

Comment: I looked up the byte and it is "MHhmZg==" which looks like the end of a certificate. Is it possible you're pulling in the Security certificate as well? Can you try it with a raw test.txt file?

Comment: When I run it locally, the same pickle loads fine using `pd.read_pickle(local_path)`. I guess maybe I could save the DataFrame using `pickle.dump()` instead?

Comment: I think you're pulling part of the certificate so it can't be read. I updated my answer to include the use of the cloud storage API.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.read_pickle` accepts a path as the first argument; you are passing a `File` object (`file.FileIO`) and a `bytes` object (`read_to_string`).

So far I have not found a way to read a pickle object directly from GCS using pandas, so you will have to copy it to the machine. You could use `file_io.copy` for that:

```
file_io.copy('gs://xxxx', '/tmp/x.pkl')
train_df = pd.read_pickle('/tmp/x.pkl')
```

Comment: I get the error: ImportError: No module named indexes.base when reading the pickle

Comment: I'm also trying:    ` f = file_io.FileIO(path_to_gcs, mode='r')` and 
   `train_df = pickle.load(f)` and it's also not working...UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: did you try `mode='rb'`?