# How to correctly read prophet model from JSON object stored in GCS

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-storage, facebook-prophet

I have a `prophet` model that I have stored to Google cloud storage folder and now I want to read this model in my code to run `prediction` pipeline. The model object was stored as JSON using this link https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/additional_topics.html

[image]

For this, first I download the JSON object locally from the bucket. And then I try to use the `model_from_json()` method. However, I keep getting below error -

```
import json
from google.cloud import bigquery, storage
from prophet.serialize import model_to_json, model_from_json

bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob('/GCSpath/to/.json')

blob.download_to_filename('mymodel.json') # download the file locally

with open('mymodel.json', 'r') as fin: m = model_from_json(json.load(fin))
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/python/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/Users/python/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I tried the method specified here too but it still does not work - [Downloading a file from google cloud storage inside a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555142/downloading-a-file-from-google-cloud-storage-inside-a-folder)

What is the correct way to save and load Prophet models?

Answer (score 1):

The error **`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte`** makes reference that either your filename or some text inside your file is not formated in UTF-8.

This means that you have some special characters inside your file that are not being able to be decoded, for example it could be Cyrillic characters or even some Unicode characters. Check this [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-unicode-utf-8-and-strings-in-python-757a232db95c) for a reference on the difference between Unicode and UTF, you will find some examples too.

I would recommend checking your files in case there are special characters that are not compatible and removing them. It also marks the position where the error was found, so you could try starting from there.

On the other hand, if reviewing file by file and removing characters is not viable, you could also try opening your files in binary.
Instead of using `'r'` in the `open()` command:

```
with open('mymodel.json', 'r') as fin: m = model_from_json(json.load(fin))
```

Try using `'rb'`:

```
with open('mymodel.json', 'rb') as fin: m = model_from_json(json.load(fin))
```

This most likely will solve your problem since reading a file in binary would not try to decode bytes to strings, hence no formatting issues. You may find more information about file reading in Python [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-read-write-file#:%7E:text=To%20open%20a%20file%20in,in%20binary%20format%20for%20writing.), and more about how or why to read files in binary [here](https://www.stackvidhya.com/python-read-binary-file/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20open%20the%20file%20using%20open()%20method%20by,binary%20file%20in%20read%20mode.&text=b%20%E2%80%93%20To%20specify%20it%27s%20a,string%20attempt%20will%20be%20made.).

Answer (score 0):

i think the error message is quite clear. 'utf-8' can not decode the format of data in your file.

when you use open(), which is a python built-in function, it expects an argument for "encoding" which is set to 'utf-8' by default.

you need to find the encoding preferable for data in your file and provide it as argument to "encoding=your-encoding-code"

Hope this helps!